# Why are these new questions not appearing in the main list?

Tags: bug, questions

The three most recently asked questions on [SciFi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) are not showing up in the [Newest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest) or [Active](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active) questions list.

- [A cartoon series about teenage monsters including a one-eyed mummy girl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269076/101407)
- [TV show where characters have a short name, and they can't remember their real name](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269080/101407)
- [Story where someone had the power to lower someone's temperature by several degrees](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/269081/101407)

They all appear to be in reasonable shape, no obvious signs of problems in their timeline or anything.  They're not locked, protected, closed...  They just simply don't show up.

Oddly, they *also* don't show up in the [Active](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartoon?tab=Active) questions by tag, but they *do* show up in the [Newest](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartoon?tab=Newest) list.  A [search](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22mummy+girl%22) will also find them, so they're not being actively hidden, they're just not being found when the main question list is being populated.

Is there something going wrong somewhere?

Comment: [A number of things seem to have broken simultaneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383417/a-number-of-things-seem-to-have-broken-simultaneously)

Comment: @Warcupine Ah, I read that post as a bunch of problems _with Meta_, not as general site problems.

Comment: That's also how I read it, but seems to be the same issue affecting multiple places.

Comment: Can replicate - but its wierdly not affecting some other sites.

Comment: @DavidW these are the problems *observed so far*. I don't think anybody has a full grasp on what is affected or not. As far as we've been able to tell, some functionalities are *consistently broken* but not predictable which functionality exactly does not work.

Comment: It's like COVID. It affects every patient (site) in a different and unpredictable way.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's why I thought it might be a problem with just those posts or just SciFi, because I checked against [bicycles.se] and that looked fine.