# SciFi.se down - Error 500?

Tags: bug, outage

I was trying to look at a question on SciFi.SE based on a web search and it's coming up with Error 500. When I went to the main page for SciFi, it also came up error 500. This is the only one of the fifteen SE sites that I participate on that this is happening. Clues?

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but [CS.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) have some serious problems too (loading on a blank page).

Comment: seems up to me. There's network wide issues at the moment tho

Comment: they work for me, atleast for now

Comment: I think it's most likely the same stuff that's causing everything listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383417/369802)... but let's add a status tag here as well and see what happens..

Comment: Meta here was down for a few minutes also. Seems related to the attempts to fix [A number of things seem to have broken simultaneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/383417/a-number-of-things-seem-to-have-broken-simultaneously).

Comment: Should be back now.

Comment: Seems to be resolved; the site appears back.

Comment: Mechanics.SE was also down.