# New activity indicator (bullet/dot) in Custom Filters no longer displaying

Tags: bug, status-review, user-interface, filtering, custom-filters

One of my favorite and most useful features here was that, when I went to a Custom Filter (e.g. Watched Tags), I used to get an indicator (dot/bullet) next to questions with new activity.  That seems to be missing over the last 3-4 days.  Possibly related to [A number of things seem to have broken simultaneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383417/902710) but not noticed in that post?

I pretty much always start every visit to a Stack Exchange site by clicking my "Watched Tags" filter, so that I can focus on questions I'm most interested in.  Of course, questions with new activity are sorted at the top (based on my filter settings), but the ability to see at a glance if there were ones with *new* activity (and which ones, specifically) was incredibly useful.  I ... miss it!

I'm surprised that I haven't found any existing questions here on Meta about this, so either:

- It's just me?
- I accidentally changed a setting somewhere that caused the New Activity indicator to go missing on questions?
- I'm the only one who cared about that feature?
- I'm just missing the duplicate Meta question?

Comment: I noticed the same, but I suspect it is unrelated.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [New question indicator has disappeared](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421294) "*It's just me?*" no, there is dozens of us.

Comment: FWIW I _do_ see the blue dot on the right sidebar when there are new questions matching a custom filter. But when I load the question list, the blue dot is gone. The only cosmetic difference I am noticing for the first time (which doesn't mean it's new!) is that clicking on the link in the Custom Filters box appends a querystring argument `&uqlId=<number>`. Which may have been there before but I don't recall ever noticing it before.

Comment: ^ ah, that point about the blue dot still appearing only in the sidebar is covered in the MSO comments.

Comment: @AaronBertrand "*the Custom Filters box appends a querystring argument &uqlId=<number>*" yeah, it's been there. It's actually slightly misleading, since it loads the filter based on its ID. The rest of the querystring is irrelevant. Which is a bit odd if you change the custom filter but go back in your history to a previous URL, since it just loads the new filter.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks!  I did check MSO first, but that was 2 days ago ;-).  I finally got around to writing up the question, and only re-checked MSE since it's a problem common to all sites.  Good to have the sanity check, though!

Comment: I miss this feature, too.  Refreshing the page used to make it easy to see where to start to see questions where I hadn't already seen the most recent activity.  Now I have to remember the top few question titles.  (Not just the top one since it might have been edited and be higher up.)  I use a custom filter query to search on a bunch of tags.

Comment: @AaronBertrand do you know if this is scheduled to be investigated / fixed?  It would be nice if this question or that on MSO got a status-review tag to show that the issue is not forgotten.

Comment: @snakecharmb I don’t know the state but I can check on January 3rd.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Any update?

Comment: @jamesdlin Escalating for triage, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @AaronBertrand did anything ever happen with this?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I only know that it's on the right team's backlog, awaiting prioritization.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I just noticed that [this area of the visual design](/q/392273/902710) is getting attention.  However, the indicator didn't seem to make it into the discussion, though, so if there's anything you can do to make sure that Chloe is aware of the need, that would be greatly appreciated!